# How do I fix the frequency of my audio?

Tags: audio, frequency

I am editing some audio files of an existing game.
The current frequency rate Im using is 6500hz and the music sounds pretty bad. P. D If I use 44100hz there will be a lot of noise.
I am using Audacity to fix the audio. The audio can play well in a computer but it plays horribly wrong on the mobile game I mentioned
Here is a link of the audio:

Comment: Sorry -- could you turn that into a question? I gather that you want some help, but... more info please, and as specific a request as possible.

Comment: I have just editted my question please help. Me

Comment: Is your question 'how to change the sampling frequency of an audio file from 6.5 kHz to 44.1 kHz without adding noise ?'

Comment: You need to sample at double the highest frequency you want to reproduce well. If you have already sampled at 6500 then you cannot make it sound better...

Comment: With 6.5 khz it already has noise. But Audacity nor any other program can detect thst noise.

Answer (score 0):

Though you should always record at 44.1.KHz, I detect another issue with the sound. You can talk about analogue processing when you are recording, but when the audio is compiled it becomes encoded digitally. This is where bit rate comes into the mix. I believe the output of your recording was encoded into MP3, exactly what bit rate have you used to output the signal? It sounds incredibly low. As a general rule of thumb, you want to have your bit rate at either 128 kbps or above. I personally prefer 320 kbps as this ensures crisp clean audio.

In summary, record it at 44.1KHz, and make sure the output is at least 128kbps MP3. Alternatively you could use wav at 24-bit encoding.

Hope this helps

Comment: I had it at 16 bit. I will try that and let you know